# Centering with CSS.

Tags: html, css

This will probably turn out to be a trivial issue, but I'm trying to center all my divs inside a container, but no matter what I try with the auto margins, everything is still aligned to the left of the page.

Anyone know what's going on?

Stuck it on jsfiddle too:

http://jsfiddle.net/eLogy4nh/

```
#page-container {   
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Any help would be awesome chaps.

Comment: You need to put a fixed `width` in order to use `magin: 0 auto;` technique. http://jsfiddle.net/eLogy4nh/1/

Comment: Please define width as well of #page-container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `#page-container` block has 100% width by default, so the `margin: 0 auto` will not do anything.

However, your block level child elements can be centered, for example:

```
#main-nav {     
   background: grey;    
   height: 30px;     
   width: 90%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You need to apply the `margin: 0 auto` to each container that you want centered within your `#page-container` parent block.

You can do this many ways with CSS, either apply the same rule to each block that needs to be centered or create a CSS class with the centering rule and then apply the class to each block, for example:

```
#page-container > div {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Note that a simpler way of getting a similar result would be to set the width of `#page-container` to 90% and let the child elements take on the full width of the parent block.

However, both techniques are valid and the one to pick may depend on other design and layout considerations, for example, the use of background images and so on.

See demo fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/resqhsoe/

Comment: Marc, Aaron, Mike, Yogesh > Thanks guys, you are all correct! , and I'd already tried those things before coming here. At first I thought I couldn't see the wood for the trees but it turns out that there was a non printable character between a colon and a value in the css. My editor wasn't showing it, but if I viewed the css online, it was right there staring me in the face. Thank you all so much for your help though! Thought I was going nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this has already been answered above...

But to center an item it will need a width, without one a block element will contain 100% of the available space.

```
#page-container { 
width: 70%;  
margin: 0px auto;
}
```